# what does this error mean in c?

Tags: c, linker

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>

int main()
{
    char a,b;
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("lext.txt","w");


    fprintf(fp,"PLUS");

return 0;
}
```

the error i get is this

```
/tmp/ccQyyhxo.o:(.eh_frame+0x11): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Please provide the command line you used that gave you this error.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are compiling a `.cpp` file with `gcc`. Rename the file to end with `.c` so it compiles as C code or compile it with the C++ driver `g++`. That will link in the `stdc++` library providing these functions.

Comment: Works both ways round for me. Not saying you're wrong, but Which bit of the c++ library do you think is necessary for this code sample?

Comment: @Neil it's implicitly referencing those exception support functions. Personality routines are defined by the Itanium C++ ABI. See http://www.codesourcery.com/public/cxx-abi/abi-eh.html#base-personality

Comment: obviously `__gxx_personality_v0`;-)

Comment: @Johannes Thanks (I guess) - I must admit to knowing nothing about codesourcery and caring less. The code does compile  & link with GCC 4.4.1 with both the g++ and the gcc drivers, on Windows, on my machine, etc. etc. :-)

Comment: @Neil if you pass `-fno-exceptions`, it compiles/links fine. I don't know how GCC's exceptions work on Windows, but apparently in a way that makes this "work". However, that's hardly a proper way. If you really want to compile that file with `GCC`, you should pass `-x c` to indicate it's a C file.

Comment: @Johannes Couldn't (and shouldn't) the linker strip out those references, since they are evidently not called - this being pure C code?

Comment: @Neil you can't know whether an `extern "C"` function you call doesn't throw (it could be defined by a C++ library, after all). If it throws, your C++ code has to do unwinding, thus it's referencing those functions even though in your code you don't directly call the function it references.

Answer (score 2):

`ld` is the linker and it is reporting that there is a link problem. The **gxx** part of the error message hints that it has something to do with a **C++** problem which makes the answer *Johannes Schaub - litb* gives about the root cause correct.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth I thought it could be good to point out how to interpret the error message and what might have led Johannes to come up with the solution.